# Using custom filter on ng-repeat causing ng-class-even/odd not to work

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a simple ng-repeat with a couple of filters applied.  Now I have added an ng-class-even class for the even results and when the filter is applied, the classes seem to remain with the original index before the filter is run.  This leaves rows in odd positions with the class 'even'.

**HTML**

```
<div data-ng-repeat="location in locations | topBranchFilter:topLocations | cityFilter:searchCity | filter:search" data-ng-class-even="'even'">
  ...
</div>
```

**Filter** (both custom filters use this simple format)

```
angular.module('App')
.filter('cityFilter', function() {
  return function( locations, searchCity ) {
    if (searchCity!=='') {
      var filtered = [];
      angular.forEach(locations, function(location) {
        if(location.BranchStationCity==searchCity){
          filtered.push(location);
        }
      });
      return filtered;
    } else {
      return locations;
    }
  };
});
```

I guess my question is, is `ng-class-even` not supported with custom filters or multiple filters?

Comment: Can be reproduced: http://plnkr.co/edit/CcdMSWj0IQ9kd9hfRZjV?p=preview (type in '4' in the filter) - seems to be a bug.
You could use CSS' `:nth-child(even)` selector for now to do the styling

Comment: Thanks.  Saw a closed issue from long ago on Github, so assumed it was my code.

Comment: @Florian Orben, Your plunkr works if you add track by: http://plnkr.co/edit/G3yzcdn3OhYHL0QU3fDj?p=preview   OP see if this fixes it for you too. Add 'track by $index' to the very end of the ng-repeat statement.

Comment: @aet That's right.  Not sure why I didn't see that searching for an answer.  Add as the answer and I will mark it as accepted. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you add 'track by $index' to your ng-repeat, it should fix this problem.

```
<div data-ng-repeat="location in locations | topBranchFilter:topLocations | cityFilter:searchCity | filter:search track by $index" data-ng-class-even="'even'">
```